# Linking with "gcc" instead of "ld" - library problems

Tags: gcc, linker

I wish to perform linking with the GCC driver ("gcc") rather than "ld", (so that I can enable [link-step optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)).

"gcc" seems to behave quite differently than "ld" though, and not accept some of the same command-line options. Worse, I think I'm getting problems to do with libraries. Using "gcc" for linking, I get a number of "undefined reference" errors. Many of them are `undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned int)'`, and `undefined reference to '__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'`.

In my setup, the library providing functions like `new` is Newlib. I'm developing in e2 Studio - a variation on Eclipse, built for developing for Renesas MCUs. e2 Studio is configured to give me a "pre-built" version of Newlib, rather than building Newlib each time I build.

In my makefile, linking is done via "ld", and works fine:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld
-o "RZ_A1H_USB_Host_Func_RSK.x"
-T"E:/Renesas e2 workspace/RZ_A1H_USB_Host_Func_RSK\HardwareDebug\LinkerSubCommand.tmp"
-T"E:\Renesas e2 workspace\RZ_A1H_USB_Host_Func_RSK\compiler_specific\GNU_e2studio-IRAM.ld"
$(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LIBRARY_GENERATOR_OUTPUTTYPE_OUTPUTS)
-L"C:\PROGRA~2\KPIT\GNUARM~1.02-\ARM-NO~1\ARM-NO~1/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi//4.9-GNUARM-NONE_v14.02/interwork" -L"C:\PROGRA~2\KPIT\GNUARM~1.02-\ARM-NO~1\ARM-NO~1/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9-GNUARM-NONE_v14.02/interwork"
-L"C:\PROGRA~2\KPIT\GNUARM~1.02-\ARM-NO~1\ARM-NO~1/arm-none-eabi/lib/interwork"
-lm
-lstdc++
-lc
-lgcc
-estart
```

However, all I have to do is replace `arm-none-eabi-ld` with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, and that causes the "undefined reference" errors described above.

Any clues? Something I need to tell "gcc" that I didn't need to tell "ld"? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Some [linker options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) are duplicated by GCC, and for those that aren't you could use `-Wl` to specify options that are sent to the actual linker (see bottom of the linked reference).

Comment: Ah thanks, I was wondering how to specify those extra options. However the main problem seems to be that simply changing the command from "ld" to "gcc" causes all those "undefined reference" errors. Would there be something extra in particular I'd need to tell gcc?

Comment: When you link with GCC, do you use the `gcc` command or the `g++` command? Because if you link with `gcc` then the C++ runtime will not be linked automatically. If you link a C++ program, then use `g++` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had been using `gcc`, but even using `g++` has the same problems. It's complaining of undefined references to a lot of things, including `sqrt`, `round`, `__aeabi_ui2f`, `strcmp`, `free`, `malloc`, `__cxa_pure_virtual`, and many more. But if I just use `ld` with the exact same command-line options, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem in the end. It was that the input files were being specified in an external file which was being referenced with this bit: `-T"E:/Renesas e2 workspace/RZ_A1H_USB_Host_Func_RSK\HardwareDebug\LinkerSubCommand.tmp"`

Specifying the input files in the normal way instead solved the problem.